# Which command in Git will revert to the last change made to a file?

Tags: git

Which commands will revert the change made below so that we go back to the previous checked-in state? (Select all that apply.)

given the output of git diff test.rb

```
$ git diff test.rb
diff --git a/test.rb b/test.rb
index ce01362..94954ab 100644
--- a/test.rb
+++ b/test.rb
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello`enter code here`
+world
```

options are

```
1.git revert test.rb
2.git checkout
3.git checkout --test.rb
4.git show master:test.rb
```

have tried with option 1 but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a new commit that undoes all of the changes introduced in , then apply it to the current branch.

```
git revert <commit>
```

Eg: 
Revert to last commit - `git revert HEAD~1`

Refer : [Git revert](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert) and [Git revert-doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

To temporarily go back to a commit & get back :

```
git checkout <commit>
```

Refer : [Undo commits & Temp switch to diff commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/2142994)

To [`stash` changes](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) made after previous commit & go back to the previous commit :

```
git stash
git stash clear
```

To remove your previous git commit :

```
git reset --hard [previous Commit SHA id here]
git push origin [branch Name] -f
```

Refer : [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Answer (score 0):

Check `git log`. Copy the commit sha you to go back to and do the following

```
git reset --hard sha
```